# Make Entity Framework object into generic class via extension class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, javascriptserializer

I have an EF object called PagePreference.  The corresponding table contains three fields: UserName(PK, varchar(200), not null), PageName(PK, varchar(700), not null), and PageState(text, null).  The PageState field contains a serialized (json) object.  I have another class file which extends this EF object via the 'partial' keyword.  The idea is that on any given page, I can create an object to contain the page state and serialize it into the PageState field in the PagePreference object.  Each page would have a different PageState object so they wouldn't be compatible with each other.  Because of this, I would like the PagePreference object to use generics (e.g. PagePreference) so that when the object is loaded, it can deserialize the page state into the appropriate class ('T').  However, when I added the generic notation to the extended PagePreference object, VisualStudio considers it a while new object.  Anyone know of a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>it's only natural that this happens since generic and non-generic classes aren't the same. There isn't a way, I'm afraid to do this directly, since the entities are autogenerated. what you can try to do, however, is [use POCOs](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/07/11/entity-framework-4-0-how-to-use-pocos.aspx) which you should be able to mold anyway you want.</strike>

After trying to test this myself, I found out that EntityFramework doesn't support generics. Even with POCOs. (maybe not yet ;) )

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll just create my own wrapper and expose the properties appropriately.